# Handle http responses differently with bluebird Promise

Tags: express, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

I'm new to promises. Seems like they should make things easier. But I can't figure this out. I want to handle a promise based on the http status code. Ie 200 vs 301 (PS this is in coffeescript)

So I'm using express and I have a promise

```
express = require 'express'
router = express.Router()
Promise = require 'bluebird'

getRequest = (options) ->
  new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
    responseData = ''
    http.get options, (response) ->
      response.on 'data', (chunk) ->
        responseData += chunk
        response.on 'end', -> resolve responseData
```

.... and I want to do something such as (and this is psuedo code really)

```
getRequest
  hostname: 'www.example.com'
  port: 80
  path: 'http://www.example.com' + some_path + '?json=1'
.then (if(response.statusCode is 200)) ->
  response = JSON.parse(response)
  res.render 'express/route',
    data: response
.then (if(response.statusCode is 301)) ->
   getRequest
     hostname: 'www.example.com'
     port: 80
     path: response.headers.location + '?json=1'
 .catch (error) ->
 next(error)
```

The point is, if the first request returns a 301, I want to issue another request using that request's new location. But it seems like all I can pass back is the response. Do I have to treat the 301 as an error? OR is there a way to write the response.on differently? Or the .then() statements? I'm really at a loss.

Comment: (and in that last .then() getRequest it would do something as a result)

Comment: Where does `getRequest` produce an object with a  `statusCode`?

Comment: well within the function you can do response.on 'data', (chunk) -> this.statusCode

Comment: Then you probably should do `resolve {status: @statusCode, data: responseData}` to access them in the `then` callbac

Answer (score 0):

I don't know coffeescript, but I'll show you the basic idea in plain Javascript and you can presumably translate it to coffeescript.  Rather than try to make separate `.then()` handlers for the different `response.statusCode` values, you can just use an if/else inside the `.then()` handler to decide what to do.

This is based on a `getRequest()` that just takes an URL and returns a promise:

```
function getRequest(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = http.get(url, function(res) {
            var res.data = "";
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                res.data += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                resolve(res);
            });
            res.on('error', function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}        

function get(url, cnt) {
    cnt = cnt || 0;
    return getRequest(url + '?json=1').then(function(response) {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            response = JSON.parse(response.data);
            res.render('express/route', {data: response.data});
        } else if (response.statusCode === 301) {
            if (cnt < 10) {
                // chain next request
                return get(response.headers.location, ++cnt);
            } else {
                // bail with error on likely redirect loop
                return Promise.reject(new Error("Likely redirect loop"));
            }
        } else {
            // decide what to do if some other response.statuscode
        }
    })
 }

 get("http://www.example.com/somepath").then(function(data) {
     // process your data here
 }, next);
```

Comment: @anthonygalligani - Did this answer your question?